# Database Storage vs Application Logic

Tags: django, django-models

I am developing an app where I have the option of storing a boolean value in database or being able to calculate it from other database queries?? Which would be a better option??

Comment: Hard question to answer. Do want advice on best performance? Is computing a value more costly than doing a db query? I do not think you have provided sufficient info to get anything but *it really depends* answers. There sure is no harm in storing it in your db. You can always delete the column afterwards.

Comment: It's too difficult to say without knowing more about your use case. I imagine that in most cases - when possible - it's quicker to simply save a boolean value intermittently instead of calculating it everytime the go. Alternatively, you could create a generic key/value table to hold calculations and static and instead work from that.

Answer (score 0):

If you store it in the **DB**:

**Cons** are:

- You might have to update it when the other relevant fields are updated or removed (through a trigger or something alike).
- You will have redundant data in your db.

**Pros** are:

- Your queries would be simpler and more readable (in general your model and code readability and maintainability would improve)
- Your queries would be faster.

So decide after considering these **questions**:

- Is the field you are talking about calculated easily or does it require a more complicated process to calculate? (involving for example a join or querying multiple tables)
- Does the value change often? are the relevant fields updated very often?
- Is the data so huge that a redundant boolean field makes any difference? (not very probable)